# Problema c, encontrar el numero mayor y menor de n numeros en un ciclo for

Tags: c, dev-c++

estaba haciendo este for y todo sale bien la media, la suma y encuentra el numero mayor.
El problema viene del numero menor, ya que este lo toma como el ultimo numero que escribí o simplemente pone un 0.
Ayuda porfaasadasfas :(

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int nums,i,num1,num2=0,may,men,j,sum=0;
    float media;
    printf("SUMA, NUMERO MAYOR Y NUMERO MENOR");
    printf("\n\nCuantos numeros quiere sumar?");
    scanf("%d",&nums);

    for(i=0;i<nums;i++)
    {
        printf("Escriba el numero: ");
        scanf("%d",&num1);

        if(num1>may)
        {
            may=num1;
        }   
        if(num1<may)
        {
            men=num1;
        }   
        j=num1;
        sum=j+sum;      
    }
    media=sum/i;
    printf("La suma total es:%d",sum);
    printf("\nLa media es:%.2f",media);
    printf("\nEl numero mayor es:%d",may);
    printf("\nEl numero menor es:%d",men);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Amigo el problema está en que cada vez que comparas el num1 con el mayor para  verificar si este es menor, muchas veces está condición no se cumplirá ya que por ejemplo

Primera Iteración
`num1=5`

`5>0 may=5`

`5<5 no se cumple la salta`

Segunda Iteración

`num1=3`

`3>5 no se cumple se mantiene may=5`

`3<5 se cumple ahora men=3`

Tercera Iteración

`num1=4`

`4>5 no se cumple se mantiene may=5`

`4<5 si se cumple por lo tanto men=4`

lo cual la variable men debería ser 3 no 4

Una forma de solucionarlo sería inicializar la variable men en un numero alto
por ejemplo

`men=10000`

y te quedara de esta forma

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>

int main(){
int nums = 0, num1=0, i=0, may=0, sum=0, j=0, men=10000;
float media;

printf("SUMA, NUMERO MAYOR Y NUMERO MENOR");
printf("\n\nCuantos numeros quiere sumar?\n");
scanf("%d",&nums);
for(i=0;i<nums;i++)
{        
    printf("Escriba el numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&num1); 
    if(num1>may) 
    {
        may=num1;
    }   
    if(num1<men) 
    {
        men=num1; 
    }   
    j=num1;
    sum=j+sum;
}
media=sum/i;
printf("\nLa suma total es: %d",sum);
printf("\nLa media es: %.2f",media);
printf("\nEl numero mayor es: %d",may);
printf("\nEl numero menor es: %d",men);

getch();
}
```

Otra forma podrías ser que definas que cuando se ingrese el primer registro men sea igual a ese por ejemplo en esta parte

```
printf("Escriba el numero: ");
scanf("%d",&num1); 
if(i==0) men=num1; //aquí declaramos la instruccion
if(num1>may) 
{
    may=num1;
}
```

Espero te sea de útilidad

Comment: Revisa tu respuesta. El código falla con valores (-1, -2, -3) y con (11000, 11001, 11002). El problema se soluciona si inicializas `may=INT_MIN;` y `men=INT_MAX`. Ambos valores salen de `#include <limits.h>`. Inicializar con el primer valor ingresado es también correcto, pero requiere código extra y se ve feo.

Comment: @CandidMoe tienes razón... sería lo más adecuado... gracias por la sugerencia :)

Answer (score 1):

Primero, cuando vas a buscar los elementos mayor y menor de un juego de datos, debes inicializar la variable `men` con el mayor valor posible para su tipo de datos. Para enteros, el mayor valor posible es INT_MAX.

Igualmente, para la variable `may`, usas el menor valor posible. Para enteros, es INT_MIN.

Ambos valores se obtienen desde `limits.h`, que contiene una serie de constantes adecuadas para la arquitectura en que trabajas.

O sea, tienes que declarar:

```
int men = INT_MAX;
int may = INT_MIN;
```

Además, tienes siempre que comparar el número contra ambos límites. ¿Por qué? Pues porque el juego de datos puede que tenga un sólo valor, con lo que `men` y `may` valen lo mismo al final.

La solución correcta es:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(){
int nums = 0, i = 0, num1 = 0, num2 = 0, may = INT_MIN, men = INT_MAX, j = 0, sum = 0;
float media;

printf("SUMA, NUMERO MAYOR Y NUMERO MENOR");
printf("\n\nCuantos numeros quiere sumar?\n");
scanf("%d",&nums);
for(i=0;i<nums;i++)
{        
    printf("Escriba el numero: ");
    scanf("%d",&num1);
        if (num1 > may) {
            may = num1;
        }
        if (num1 < men) {
            men = num1;
        }
    j=num1;
    sum=j+sum;
}
media=sum/i;
printf("\nLa suma total es: %d",sum);
printf("\nLa media es: %.2f",media);
printf("\nEl numero mayor es: %d",may);
printf("\nEl numero menor es: %d",men);
}
```

produce:

**Caso un solo valor**

```
Cuantos numeros quiere sumar?
1
Escriba el numero: 15 

La suma total es: 15
La media es: 15.00
El numero mayor es: 15
El numero menor es: 15
```

**Con dos valores**

```
Cuantos numeros quiere sumar?
2
Escriba el numero: 20
Escriba el numero: 15

La suma total es: 35
La media es: 17.00
El numero mayor es: 20
El numero menor es: 15
```

**Con tres valores**

```
Cuantos numeros quiere sumar?
3
Escriba el numero: -3
Escriba el numero: -1
Escriba el numero: -2

La suma total es: -6
La media es: -2.00
El numero mayor es: -1
El numero menor es: -3
```

**Otra más**

```
Cuantos numeros quiere sumar?
3
Escriba el numero: 11003
Escriba el numero: 11001
Escriba el numero: 11002

La suma total es: 33006
La media es: 11002.00
El numero mayor es: 11003
El numero menor es: 11001
```